# Creating a grid of LAT -90 to 90 and -180 to 90

Tags: r

I would like to create a grid and I used this:

```
reso = 0.25
xs <- seq(-180, 180, by=reso)
ys <- seq(-90, 90, by=reso)
grd <- expand.grid(
  x=xs,
  y=ys,
  presence=0
)
head(grd)
```

Which gives me this,

```
    x   y presence
1 -180.00 -90        0
2 -179.75 -90        0
3 -179.50 -90        0
4 -179.25 -90        0
5 -179.00 -90        0
6 -178.75 -90        0
```

However, I want this,

```
x             y        presence
-179.875    -89.875     0
-179.875    -89.625     0
-179.875    -89.375     0
-179.875    -89.125     0
-179.875    -88.875     0
-179.875    -88.625     0
-179.875    -88.375     0
-179.875    -88.125     0
-179.875    -87.875     0
-179.875    -87.625     0
-179.875    -87.375     0
-179.875    -87.125     0
-179.875    -86.875     0
-179.875    -86.625     0
-179.875    -86.375     0

Please note how the x and y increases.
```

Comment: `xs <- seq(-179.875, 179.875, reso); ys <- seq(-89.875, 89.875, reso)`?

Comment: It is not clear what sequence you want.  Please update your question with a better example.

Comment: looks like this reso = 0.25 xs <- seq(-180, 180, by=reso) ys <- seq(-90, 90, by=reso) grd <- expand.grid( x=xs, y=ys, presence=0 ) head(grd)

Comment: This would be a tonne easier to interpret if you used a very minimal example like `reso = 1; xs <- seq(-90, -88, by=reso); ys <- seq(-180, -178, by=reso)` which would produce a result with 9 rows instead of 1038961 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
reso <- 0.25
xs <- seq(-179.875, 179.875, reso)
ys <- seq(-89.875, 89.875, reso)
grd <- expand.grid(y=ys, x=xs, presence=0)
grd <- grd[,c(2,1,3)]
head(grd)
#          x       y presence
# 1 -179.875 -89.875        0
# 2 -179.875 -89.625        0
# 3 -179.875 -89.375        0
# 4 -179.875 -89.125        0
# 5 -179.875 -88.875        0
# 6 -179.875 -88.625        0
```

Comment: Nice job interpreting the question. So the pattern with `expand.grid` is right-to-left in terms of the repetitions of each group - e.g. : `expand.grid(1:3, letters[1:3], letters[4:6])`

Comment: @thelatemail  Yes, it works like this. That's why here your have to switch the "dimensions" to get the expected output.

Comment: Many thanks guys, this work . Let me see if it works with my model

Comment: [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?